# How to get the option to add product catalog in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I use visual studio 2012 ultimate to access TFS 2012. In the TFS view catalog screen, i do not get the option to add a new Product catalog to the list. I could only add the catalog in the home page as a requirement. Is there any configuration change i need to make to get this option?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is the sprint backlog view, from that view you can click the plus to add tasks to one of the backlog items already in the sprint.

If you click Product Backlog it will bring you to the Backlog view where you can add new items to the backlog and drag drop them to assign to sprints.